# googleFormsの回答をメールで受け取りたい

Tags: google-apps-script

googleFormsの回答をメールで受け取りたい

目的は、googleFormsの回答をメール本文（カンマ形式）
フォームの回答は
１、人の名前(minamiDR、matumotoDR、nakataniDR、nakanoDR)
２、ゴミ箱番号（01-20)
３、作業内容（回収、清掃、点検、修理）

本文には、
年、日、時間、名前、ゴミ箱番号、作業内容
としたい

作りながら学びたいと思っています。
ご教授のほどお願いいたします

Comment: 作り方を1から教えてくださいという質問はこのサイトでは好まれません。" Google form メール送信"ぐらいのキーワードで解説サイトがいくつも引っかかりますので、まずはそういうのを見ながら試してみるとよいです。そこで具体的な疑問にぶつかったときはそれについて質問してください

Comment: コメント,ありがとうございます。早速調べてみます。

Answer (score 0):

こういう感じになりますが・・

```
function MailSend() {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    const sh = ss.getSheetByName("フォームの回答");
    const LastRow=sh.getLastRow();       
      
      const recipient = '送信したいメールアドレス'; 
      const subject = 'メールのタイトル';
      const time = sh.getRange(LastRow,1).getValue();
      const name = sh.getRange(LastRow,2).getValue(); 
      const DustNum = sh.getRange(LastRow,3).getValue();
      const Work = sh.getRange(LastRow,4).getValue();     
  
      let body = '';    
      body += '年月日時刻'+ time+'\n';
      body += '名前'+ name +'\n';   
      body += 'ゴミ箱番号'+ DustNum +'\n';
      body += '作業内容'+ Work +'\n';       
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);  
      //フリーの場合はMailAppを　GmailAppにする
    
  }
```

Comment: ちなみに　トリガー設定をしないとフォーム回答時には動作しません